# How do I find help for point command `.` in *nix?

Tags: linux, unix

I need to find help for point command `.` such as in `. ./my_script.sh` (I mean  the first point.)

I have already tried to find a man page using `man .` and `man \.`. How can I display a man page in which it explains the use of command `.`?

Comment: @n8te I am referring to the first point in `. ./my_script.sh`. I know it is not the same to execute `. ./my_script.sh` than `./my_script.sh`. `. ./my_script.sh` will behave similar than `source ./my_script.sh`

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I didn't see the first dot.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus: The [canonical name](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) for "." is FULL STOP. What people call it depends on where they were raised.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/728931/what-does-bashrc-actually-do

Comment: Just run: `help .`

Comment: In the docs, though, it's called `dot`. See the formal specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/dot.html

Comment: Perhaps the first thing you need to realize is that "." and ".." are NOT commands.  They are parts of paths.  "." means the current directory, so if you type "./some_file" at a prompt, the system will try to execute that file in the current directory.  But if you type say "vi ./some_file", it will run vi to edit the file.  Likewise, ".." means the parent directory.

Comment: @jamesqf `.` is a command, specifically a shell builtin. In Bash it's equivalent to `source`.

Comment: @wjandrea: The OP is asking about *nix, not bash, which is not the only shell in existence.  "." may be a command in bash (there doesn't appear to be a man page for bash on my system), but I use a different shell in which it does not appear to be.  If you expect bash-specific things to apply to *nix in general, you will eventually be disappointed :-)

Comment: @jamesqf I mentioned Bash just to give some context, if you were more familiar with it. In the Bourne shell, `.` is a shell builtin.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Though true in the context of Unicode canonical names, unfortunately, that was a misleading choice on the part of the consortium. In reality, "full stop" is the name of a punctuation mark in English, which is usually represented by the symbol `.`, whose name is "period" (and which has many other uses, including the use discussed in the question). This is similar to how an "exclamation mark" is "implemented" by the symbol `!`, which is called "pling". Other uses for pling include the _factorial_ notation in mathematics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I easily see the man page for builtin shell commands?](https://superuser.com/questions/587026/how-can-i-easily-see-the-man-page-for-builtin-shell-commands)

Comment: @jamesqf: `.` is POSIX, not just bash. E.g. it's also in zsh and ksh.

Comment: The official name of the command is [dot](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot).

Comment: @MSalters: Isn't in tcsh, though, which was my point.  It applies to particular shells, not universally.

Comment: `man command` takes to the common man page for all builtin commands and `help command` shows the command specific information.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

First of all you should invoke `type .`, you will probably get something like:

> ```
> . is a shell builtin
> ```

Builtins are parts of your shell, they don't have their own manual pages. Some of them may seem to have them though, e.g. `echo` is a builtin in Bash but most likely there is a separate executable like `/bin/echo` in your system and in this case `man echo` refers to the *latter*. These two `echo`s are probably not strictly equivalent.

Your shell may provide information about any builtin via `help` builtin; try `help help`, `help type` and finally:

```
help .
```

Builtins may also be listed in your shell's manual page. E.g. (in my Debian) Bash builtins are covered directly in `man bash`, yet for Zsh builtins `man zsh` tells me to run `man zshbuiltins`. In general shells may or may not explain their builtins.

Comment: +1 for pointing that `.` is a shell-built-in and This should be marked as answer because OP asks `how to find help for . in *nix ?`.

Comment: +1 for the use of `type .` to demonstrate that some commands are shell builtins.

Comment: On most Debian, Bash builtins are also extracted to the `bash-builtins(1)` manual page, which is of a more convenient size.

Comment: Also, invoking "type" only works if you're using a shell which has a "type" builtin.  If you happen to be using tcsh, "type ." gives "type: Command not found."

Comment: +1 for the use of `type .` to tell you what to research next. Lego.

Comment: Even `. --help` works

Comment: So I tried "`help .`" and I get "`help: no entry for . in the manual.`".  (Same for "`help source`", giving "`help: no entry for source in the manual.`")  I suspect that if you're experiencing more elaborate output, that may be a bash-ism (and suspect that is why this entry ended up getting upvoted so much)

Answer (score 24):

Try using `man sh` or `man bash` or the man page for whatever shell you are using.  (Maybe `man $SHELL`.)

This is officially not called the "point" command, but the `source` command.  Searching for the word `source` may be helpful.

e.g., [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (search for "each builtin command"), and you'll quickly find the documentation.

As for explaining the use, I can do that right here.  I will just refer to this as the `source` command, recognizing that it can be abbreviated to just a period when you're using some shells, and with some shells that command might need to be (because dot might be recognized but the entire word `source` might not be).

If you use the `source` command, your shell will read each line from the script file, and try to execute it.  You need "read" permissions on the file.  (It doesn't matter if you have "execute" permissions.)  If you modify a variable, that is prone to affecting your current shell.

If, on the other hand, you just try to execute the file, then your shell will ask the operating system to take care of this request.  This will require "execute" permissions.  (On some systems, like OpenBSD, you won't need "read" permissions for this.  On other systems, including many Unix variations, you will.)  The file may need to start with an appropriate header (e.g., `#!/bin/sh`) so the operating system recognizes this to be a script file.  The operating system will execute a copy of the requested shell, and tell that shell to run the contents of the script.  If the shell environment is changed (e.g., a variable gets a new value, the working directory is changed (with `cd`), a file descriptor is redirected (with `exec`), etc.), it will impact only the sub-shell that was called for the script, and can't modify the environment in the parent shell that called the script file.

Comment: It's only `source` in bash. In the POSIX specification, it's called "the dot command" (and the `source` alias is not supported).

Comment: A script needs read permissions, otherwise the interpreter can't access it. See [Can a script be executable but not readable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34202/117037)

Comment: Executing a script doesn't open a sub-shell, but just a normal child process, just like running a compiled program. See [this answer on "Is a sub-shell the same thing as a child-shell?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261661/117037)

Comment: So, I type `man bash` and then what, `/.`? Not very useful. `/source` would be useful, but for that you'd need to know that `.` and `source` are the same thing.

Comment: @Joker_vD : On most systems I've come across, there is no man page for "." or "source", so the only official documentation related to this command is the text located in the man page for the shell. I simply answered the question of where a person can find that official documentation, since that is what aturegano asked. Right. If you use / to search, and search for period, you get lots of  unrelated periods. Hey! Don't blame me if the man page's design isn't clear enough for you to like it. I didn't design this.  I'm just helping to *successfully* deal with how things actually are.

Comment: @wjandrea : Tests have found that exact effect depends on what system is being used.  Question was tagged with both unix and linux, so my earlier statement was just as accurate and applicable as your early comment that indicated different behavior.  There are different results in different environments.  Sometimes, such read permission is required to "execute" a script, as you noted.  In other environments, such permissions are not needed.  (I've updated the text of the answer to better mention the different possibilities that may be experienced.)

Comment: I found your paragraph "As for explaining the use..." slightly misleading, since it implies that it _might_ be `.` and it _might_ be `source`, but as @CharlesDuffy already mentioned, it's _always_ `.` in any POSIX-compliant shell and only has the alias `source` in one shell.

Comment: @TomFenech : I wasn't misleading.  I very much was saying specifically that.  No implication was intended.  Charles Duffy was wrong.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : bash offers both commands ; this does not mean that one command but not the other is universally accepted.  In fact, I have found evidence proving that is not true, in both directions.  In OpenBSD's ksh, dot works but the word "source" does not.  In csh, it is called "souce", and not dot.  If you try to run dot, it will try to "run" the filesystem object called dot (the current directory) and you'll get a permissions issue.  (The question did not rule out csh, as it specified operating systems, but not what shell was being referred to.)

Comment: Bringing up csh and tcsh is essentially obfuscation. I know of no distro where csh or tcsh is default; POSIX-y shells are both de facto and de jure standard, to the point that the StackOverflow shell tag explicitly indicates that POSIX is to be assumed in any discussion within that tag absent explicit contrary specification (granted, I haven't checked the tag wiki here on SU).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : I don't use either, and didn't offhand recall which shells didn't support dot or source (I had to go checking), but I always remembered that neither command is universally supported.  Alleging obfuscation seems like a rather attacking claim and I defend my intent of not trying to mislead. When I answered, I simply tried to support choice and compatibility.  When I was first introduced to Unix, I was taught csh was viable and the most proper approach was to support it. (I've since read a bit more about csh's bugginess and general unsuitability.) I wasn't aware POSIX excluded csh

Answer (score 6):

No one else has mentioned it, as it's often forgotten.

Your biggest clue would of come from the helpful command `whatis`.

```
tim@musha ~ $ whatis .
builtins (1)         - bash built-in commands, see bash(1)
tim@musha ~ $ whatis source
builtins (1)         - bash built-in commands, see bash(1)
tim@musha ~ $ whatis bash
bash (1)             - GNU Bourne-Again SHell
tim@musha ~ $ whatis lynx
lynx (1)             - a general purpose distributed information browser for the World Wide Web
tim@musha ~ $ whatis linux
linux: nothing appropriate.
tim@musha ~ $ whatis whatis
whatis (1)           - display one-line manual page descriptions
```

**EDIT:**

Some people have pointed out in the comments that this isn't in some distrobutions - maybe it's an installable package, or enabled some how - I had it by default in gentoo ;)

It includes the wonderful which - which tells you which executable is called, and whereis which gives you all the paths to a executable you name, and it's man pages (if it exists in multiple paths).

Comment: Good hint but it seems it not works everywhere. For instance, in AIX with ksh, `whatis .` returns `man: 0703-307 . is not found.`

Comment: `whatis .` returns nothing on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: And ".: nothing appropriate." on OpenSuSE using tcsh.

Comment: Ah, from it's own man page: *"whatis - display one-line manual page descriptions."* So it appears to be a very very short version of man.

Comment: A more compatible option may be: apropos (which should be the same as running "man -k").  For "." or "source" (which is part of the word "resource") this doesn't work too well, due to too many false positives, but likely would work for your other examples (bash, lynx, and whatis).  On Debian Linux: "`whatis .`" gave "`.: nothing appropriate.`"  on OpenBSD, it resulted in 47 lines of output.  For this specific example (using "`whatis .`" in Gentoo), the results may happen to just be uncommonly good (meaning that this technique isn't generally as useful for many other example scenarios).

Comment: @TOOGAM .... it may work well for you, but tim@musha ~ $ apropos . | wc -l
13250

Answer (score 4):

`man source` will show the explanation that you need.

The dot is the same as the source command.

`source` executes the script in the current shell instead of in a subshell (it's the usual way).

Using `source` the variables set inside the script are preserved after the script has finished.

Comment: In what distro(s) does `man source` work? Not in my Debian, hence the question.

Comment: It works in  CentOS 6.5. I guess is more related to the version of bash. In my case is 4.1.2(1)

Comment: @jcbermu, no version of bash ships a separate man page for `source` upstream -- that's more likely something CentOS did.

Comment: On my system, `man source` gives you ``man bash_builtins``, which doesn’t explain anything,  but refers you to `bash(1)`

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu LTS) `man source` gives me `source(3tcl)`... `type command` and then if the command is a builtin `help command` is probably the proper way...

Answer (score 0):

The `.` is a synonym for the shell `source` command and so in **bash**, its syntax is displayed by...

```
help source
```

It functions exactly like the `include` and `import` commands in other languages in that it reads the target file and interprets it as if it were part of the current script. Thus, that file will execute in its entirety before the commands in the rest of the current script.

It should usually be at the beginning of the current script and is most often used to load variables and/or function definitions.